# En python, ¿cómo hago para comparar una fecha ingresada por teclado contra la actual?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ingreso una fecha por teclado, quiero comparar (mes "x" == mes "y") pero me toma solo el mes "x", debería darme 1 si son iguales y 2 si son diferentes. ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

```
from datetime import date 
from datetime import datetime 
from datetime import timedelta 
now = datetime.now() 
while True: 
    fecha_str=input('\n Ingrese fecha "aaaa/mm/dd"...: ') 
    try: 
        fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha_str, '%Y/%m/%d').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        print("\n Tu fecha es: ",str(fecha))
    
    except ValueError:
        print("\n No ha ingresado una fecha correcta...")
    else:
        break 
      
def mes_Mes():
    fecha = date.today().month #mes(y) ingresado por teclado
    today = datetime.now().month #mes(x) 
    if today == fecha:
        asigna_mes=1
        print(asigna_mes) # los "print" son solo para verificar que este funcionando
    else:
        asigna_mes2=2
        print(asigna_mes2)

    print(today) 
    print(now)
mes_Mes()
```

Comment: Hay algunas inconsistencias en tu código. Declaras `now` al inicio pero luego creas otra variable `today` con la única diferencia que `today` es el mes de la fecha actual (Podrías utilizar `month` de la variable `now`). Creas `fecha` en el `while` pero luego la reemplazas por `date.today().month` pero el comentario dice que es el mes ingresado por teclado pero no es correcto ya que lo reemplazaste. Aparte de eso, es mejor que definas las variables en el mismo idioma y que los nombres de las variables sean significativos.

Comment: Estas comparando el mes actual consigo mismo, por eso no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Como puse en los comentarios, la razón por la que no funciona es porque estás comparando siempre el mes actual con el mes actual. En otras palabras, estás comparando

```
date.today().month == datetime.now().month
```

Tanto `today().month` como `now().month` contienen el mes actual.

**Nota:** Al programar es mejor utilizar todas las variables en un solo idioma para evitar nombrar variables que no sean significativas, es decir, que no expresen su significado a través del nombre.

La solución es simple, utilizar el mes de la variable ingresada en lugar de comparar el mes actual consigo mismo

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

hoy = datetime.now() 

while True:
    # Intentamos obtener una fecha con formato aaaa/mm/dd
    try:
        # Obtenemos la fecha ingresada por el usuario
        fecha = datetime.strptime(input('Ingrese fecha "aaaa/mm/dd"...: '), '%Y/%m/%d')
        # Imprimimos la fecha ingresada pero con formato dd-mm-aaaa
        print('Tu fecha es: ', fecha.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
        # Interrumpir el while
        break
    
    # Si la fecha tiene formato incorrecto ejecutamos el except
    except ValueError:
        print("\n No ha ingresado una fecha correcta...")


def mes_Mes():
    mes_ingresado = fecha.month #mes(y) ingresado por teclado. Ahora sí es el ingresado ppor teclado
    mes_actual = hoy.month #mes(x). Que es el mes actual
    if mes_actual == mes_ingresado:
        print(1) # los "print" son solo para verificar que este funcionando
        return 1
    else:
        print(2)
        return 2
    
    print(hoy)
mes_Mes()
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```
Ingrese fecha "aaaa/mm/dd"...:  5a

 No ha ingresado una fecha correcta...
Ingrese fecha "aaaa/mm/dd"...:  2022/09/13
Tu fecha es:  13-09-2022
1
1
```

Comment: HeytalePazguato Agradecido. Si sabía que estaba comparando la misma fecha, no sabía cómo no hacerlo gracias

Comment: Buen día @JesusOrosmanRamirez, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).